# QScrollArea won't acknowledge set widget's size

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to implement a pinterest-like UI and I've been experimenting with the FlowLayout example for PySide.

The problem is that I'm trying to use a QScrollArea and it won't let me scroll down enough. In other words, I can't get to the bottom of the widget I'm trying to scroll.

You can get the hole file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-vcARNmtIHna1pReHhsRUdCeDQ/view?usp=sharing). If you download it and run it, the problem will become pretty obvious.

My code was taken from [here](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py), with these modifications:

Added this class: (it just let's me generate colored and numerated rectangles)

```
class ColoredRectangle(QLabel):
count = 0

def __init__(self, height, color):
    super(ColoredRectangle, self).__init__()

    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Background, color)

    self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.setPalette(palette)

    self.setFixedSize(200, height)
    self.setText(str(ColoredRectangle.count))
    ColoredRectangle.count += 1
```

Now I'm adding rectangles instead of buttons...

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()

    flowLayout = FlowLayout()
    flowLayout.addWidget(ColoredRectangle(450, Qt.white))
    flowLayout.addWidget(ColoredRectangle(200, Qt.green))self.setLayout(flowLayout)

    self.setLayout(flowLayout)

    self.setWindowTitle("Flow Layout")
```

Changed the `doLayout` method like this:

```
def doLayout(self, rect):

    if not any(self.itemList):
        return

    firstItem = self.itemList[0]

    x = rect.x()
    y = rect.y()

    wid = firstItem.widget()

    spaceX = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(QtGui.QSizePolicy.PushButton,
                                                            QtGui.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    spaceY = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(QtGui.QSizePolicy.PushButton,
                                                            QtGui.QSizePolicy.PushButton, QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

    itemWidth = firstItem.sizeHint().width()

    # calculate column count

    columnCount = (rect.width() + spaceX) / (itemWidth + spaceX)
    availablePositions = [None] * columnCount

    for i in range(columnCount):
        availablePositions[i] = QPoint(x + i * (itemWidth + spaceX), y)

    for item in self.itemList:

        currentPosition = availablePositions[0]
        currentPositionColumn = 0

        positionColumn = 0
        for position in availablePositions:
            if min(currentPosition.y(), position.y()) != currentPosition.y():
                currentPositionColumn = positionColumn
                currentPosition = position

            positionColumn += 1

        # update available position in column
        itemSize = item.sizeHint()
        availablePositions[currentPositionColumn] = QPoint(currentPosition.x(),
                                                           currentPosition.y() + itemSize.height() + spaceY)

        # place item
        item.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(currentPosition, itemSize))
```

And finally, I added the QScrollArea:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = Window()
scrollArea = QScrollArea()
scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
scrollArea.setWidget(mainWin)
scrollArea.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found the answer on my own...

Apparently the layout has to define the method `heightForWidth`, which, as far as I understand, returns the height of the layout which results after a width resize. So... I had to store the new height at the end of `doLayout` so I'm able to return it when asked for.

This is what I did after `doLayout`:

```
self.heightForWidthValue = max(map(lambda position : position.y(), availablePositions))
```

Also, I implemented these functions in `FlowLayout`:

```
def hasHeightForWidth(self):
    return True

def heightForWidth(self, width):
    return self.heightForWidthValue
```

And set `0` as the default value (initialized in `FlowLayout->__init__`) for `heightForWidthValue`.

Now it works like a charm :)

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-vcARNmtIHnUFpJSEZ2d2gtb2s/view?usp=sharing)'s the proper code, if anyone is interested.